# 403 page when clicking on activation link in email

Tags: users, emails

When a user creates an account, they must activate their account by verifying the email. The token in that email is the default one, i.e. `[user:one-time-login-url]`

But when the user clicks on the link in their email, they get the 403 page (= You are not authorized to see this page).

Can anybody explain why this 403 page shows up?

Comment: check the permission for authenticate user.

Comment: which permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the [User Registration Password](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword) module, which I've installed in order to set password for users before sending email to them.

I had completely forgotten about having this module installed. Sorry it was just a bug in the module.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the right to anonymous role to view published content

your_domain/?q=admin/people/permissions

then, tick view published content

Comment: please elaborate - include where to find the information on the site for the OP, or include a screenshot of the permissions page where the change needs to be made